# How to change state of a single component in ReactJS without rendering the whole component again?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I'm new to ReactJS and have a question about how I can change the state of a specific component that was instantiated inside a Map function.
Let's say I have a simple component called *panels*, and inside I have N **panel-item**, panel-item is only a single component instantiated N times with Map function inside panels. Something like this:

```
class Panels extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super();
   
    this.state = {
       panelItems: [ 
        { id: '1', text: 'A' },
        { id: '2', text: 'B' },
        { id: '3', text: 'C' },
       ]
    };
}

render() {
    return (
      <div>
          {this.state.panelItems.map(item => (
              <PanelItems key={item.id}>{item.text}</PanelItems>
          ))}
      </div>
    )
}

}

export default Panels;
```

Now some questions that I have:

1. Let's say that I wanted a button that change the state (precisely the text) of the panel item 1 to D, how can I do this?
2. If I did the question 1, will it re-render the whole Panels component (including the panel items 2 and 3)?
3. If yes, how can I only re-render the component panel item 1 without
   creating a separate component to each panel item? Because they use the
   same structure, only the data inside will change.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> …a button that changes the state (precisely the text) of the panel item 1…

Create a function that splices in the change:

```
const updateText = (index, text) => {
  // get the existing panel items from state.
  // we don't want to mutate the original so we make a copy using spread syntax
  const panelItems = [...this.state.panelItems];

  panelItems.splice(
    index, // starting at item "index"
    1, // delete one item from the array
    { ...panelItems[index], text } // and insert its replacement
);

  this.setState({ panelItems }); // set state with the new array
}
```

Then invoke that function with an onClick on the button:

```
<button onClick={() => updateText(0, 'the new text')}>Update Item 0</Button>
```

> If I did the question 1, will it re-render the whole Panels component…

As a general rule, React won't re-render a pure component if props don't change. So I'd expect your example code to to work without re-rendering every PanelItem.

> how can I only re-render the component panel item 1 without creating a separate component to each panel item

If you *are* seeing unnecessary re-renders, you might try having the loop render a component that just takes an item prop:

```
{this.state.panelItems.map(item => (
  <Items key={item.id} item={item} />
))}
```

Where the `Item` component is what you're already doing:

```
const Item => ({item}) => <PanelItem>{item.text}</PanelItem>
```

As long as the item prop is the same object it shouldn't re-render, even when the parent state changes.